# Extract records having all numbers in the string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column of 'string' data type. It has some records that are only numbers in the string and some that are actual strings. I want to extract records where this column has all numbers in the string.

For example,

```
column_A
abcd
1234
6754
defg
1100
```

The result should look like-

```
column_A
1234
6754
1100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(column_A, r'^\d+$')
```

If to apply to sample data in your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abcd' column_A UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234' UNION ALL
  SELECT '6754' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'defg' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1100' 
)
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(column_A, r'^\d+$')
```

result is

```
Row column_A     
1   1234     
2   6754     
3   1100
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use `safe_cast()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where safe_cast(column_A as int64) is not null;
```